# Hugo not using local git config

Tags: go, hugo

I'm trying to use a private theme/module with a personal access token. I can get this working by adding the following to my global `git config`.

`git config --global url."https://{USER}:{TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"`

Then running `hugo mod get -u` it will pull changes as expected.
I don't want this set in my global config and if I set it locally I get an error, because Go doesn't seem to be using the local config.

Set my configurations locally within the root of the site/repository:

`git config --local url."https://{USER}:{TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"`

Then running `hugo mod get -u` I get the following error:

```
go get: module github.com/USER/REPOSITORY: git ls-remote -q origin in /var/folders/26/gqnv01_55p964v8yz39d51fw0000gn/T/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/b410fc7b91fbc1121b5f6ec2bb2711c27cd172b4084c213e1430a33cde552597: exit status 128:
    remote: Repository not found.
    fatal: repository 'https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/' not found
```

How can I get Go/Hugo to use my local git config rather than the global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a directory replacement mapping to the site’s config, instead of modifying the git url. This points to my locally cloned theme and updates the served site whenever I modify the theme.

```
module:
     imports:
       path: 'github.com/[USER]/[REPO-NAME]'
     replacements: 'github.com/[USER]/[REPO-NAME] -> ../../[REPO-NAME]/'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`hugo mod` source code](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/d90e37e0c6e812f9913bf256c9c81aa05b7a08aa/commands/mod.go#L171-L189), `hugo` will look for a `go.mod` in your project:

```golang
filepath.Walk(dirname, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if info.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    if info.Name() == "go.mod" {
        // Found a module.
        dir := filepath.Dir(path)
        fmt.Println("Update module in", dir)
```

Check where your go.mod is, and do (in that `go.mod` parent folder):

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

That will tell you if your expected local config is actually there or not.
Look for any `.git` folder which would indicate a nested git repository/submodule, which would ignore your initial `git config --local` command

An [issue like 34513](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34513) seems to suggests though that `go mod` won't take into account the local repository:

> The git configuration only affects operations on the underlying git repo.
>
> The error that you're seeing is coming from before that, when the `go` command is attempting to resolve the repo for the requested package path.

The [official documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#private-module-repo-auth) only references the global config `.gitconfig`.

Comment: Hi @Vonc thanks for your response. The go.mod file is within the root directory of the site/repository and there are no nested .git folders. The only .git folder is within the root of the site/repository. 
git config -l --show-origin looks fine, --show-scope appears to be an invalid option.

if I run `git config --list` the local configurations are present in the local git configuration and look fine. Go just won't use the local configuration and is only working off the global configuration

Comment: @greystash Can you update first your Git? That way, show-scope will be recognized.

Comment: @greystash I have updated the answer with a reference to an issue which seems to suggests the `go mod` command would ignore a local config anyway.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I ended up finding a better solution than modifying the git config - see my other comment